# app.module.js file is missing latest version Angular

Tags: angular

i am beginner of angular. After installed angular cli and angular marital ui after I open project check the folder and files app.module.js file is missing why what is reason i don't know. Instead of that shows **app.config.ts.** what I tried is I went lot of articles online but not help me.please give me the solution for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the release of Angular v17, the CLI now creates standalone apps by default.

So when you create a new project you won't have any modules in it if you don't specify anything.

I recommand you have a look at the brand new tutorials on the new Angular documentation : https://angular.dev/tutorials

PS: It is still possible to create a module-based apps by using the `--no-standalone` flag : `ng new --no-standalone`